# php function return from db and call the value from separated view file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

Originally I was trying to pull data from database using php function.

function.php

```
function profileload($loginuser) {
    $data = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT fullname,username,contactno,email FROM account WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($loginuser) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row = array_map('stripslashes', $row);
        $data[] = $row;
    }
return $data;
}
```

view.php, the file that retrieves the data I want one by one

```
echo profileload($login_session)->fullname; // retrieve fullname of current login user
echo profileload($login_session)->username; // retrieve username of current login user
echo profileload($login_session)->contactno; // retrieve contactno of current login user
echo profileload($login_session)->email; // retrieve email of current login user
```

Whenever I try to call it, it gives me an error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object". Currently I am using this code on view.php, its working very well, just wondering if I can make the code shorter like the above code.

```
$info = profileload($login_session);
foreach($info as $data) {
    $fullname= $data['fullname'];
    $username= $data['username'];
    $contactno= $data['contactno'];
    $email= $data['email'];
}
echo $fullname; etc...
```

Comment: `$data` is an array which returned by your function. You are not supposed to treat/access like an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `profileload()` returning `array` not `object`:

Try:

```
echo profileload($login_session)[0]['fullname']; // retrieve fullname of current login user
echo profileload($login_session)[0]['username']; // retrieve username of current login user
echo profileload($login_session)[0]['contactno']; // retrieve contactno of current login user
echo profileload($login_session)[0]['email']; // retrieve email of current login user
```

Better way is instead of calling function 4 times call only one times and use it again and again. If you call function 4 times it will hit 4 times same query. Use following:

```
$user = profileload($login_session);
echo $user[0]['fullname']; // retrieve fullname of current login user
echo $user[0]['username']; // retrieve username of current login user
echo $user[0]['contactno']; // retrieve contactno of current login user
echo $user[0]['email']; // retrieve email of current login user
```

If you want to fetch as object use [**mysql_fetch_object()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: sorry, im pretty new to php, how do i make it returning an object and view the fullname as example?

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look